# Expresso Store - Emails and SMTP

Tags: expresso-store, devdemon, expresso

We're using EE 2.9 and Expresso Store 2.3.1.  Automatic emails sent when an order is placed work fine with PHP Mail and Sendmail, but wont send over SMTP. The client wants to switch to SMTP, we've added the username, password etc.. to EEs email settings, is there anything else we ned to change?

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved, in settings email sender name and email address were swapped around